# Retrieve Alias From SharedMailbox

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I would like to retrieve the alias email that would have been emailed to a Shared Mailbox but Exchange overrides the "To recipient" with the Primary email address of the shared mailbox

Example - "aa@alias.co.uk" Alias is emailed on the shared mailbox. I would like to retrieve the "aa@alias.co.uk" email

PrimaryEmail -   aa@primarydomain.co.uk

Alias Email       - aa@alias.co.uk

I have tried accessing the headers of the email but, no luck

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace readSharedMailbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExchangeService _service;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Registering Exchange connection");
                _service = new ExchangeService
                {
                    Credentials = new WebCredentials("*******", "********")
                };
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("new ExchangeService failed. Press enter to exit:");
                return;
            }
            // Office365 webservice URL
            _service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reading mail");
                FindItemsResults<Item> result = _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(1));

                foreach (Item item in result)
                {
                    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(_service, item.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("Reading items");
                    Console.WriteLine(message.ToRecipients[0].Address.ToString());
                    /* Reading the Header

                    foreach (var property in message.InternetMessageHeaders)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(property.Value);
                    }
                    */
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error has occured. \n:" + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Exchange always resolves the sender and recipients to their GAL objects - you no longer have one-off SMTP entries, but GAL objects. Retrieving the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F`) and manually parsing the To/CC headers is the only way to see the original SMTP address that the message was sent to. But even then, I have seen cases when the MIME headers were mangled by Exchange and no longer contained SMTP addresses, just the display names.